# Unable to create foreign key reference with different column lables

Tags: mysql

While I am creating schema "Cannot add foreign key constraint" error I am getting.

Query is :

```
CREATE database sample;
USE sample;

CREATE TABLE sys_admin_user_t (
  sys_admin_id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL,
  admin_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  admin_password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (sys_admin_id)
);

CREATE TABLE sys_user_roles_t (
  role_id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL,
  privilege_id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL,
  role_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  role_description VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  created_by MEDIUMINT NOT NULL,
  created_date DATE NOT NULL,
  modified_by MEDIUMINT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (privilege_id) REFERENCES privileges_t (privilege_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (created_by) REFERENCES sys_admin_user_t(sys_admin_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (modified_by) REFERENCES sys_admin_user_t(sys_admin_id),
  PRIMARY KEY (role_id)
);
```

Kindly some one help me to resolve this.

Comment: Does the table `privileges_t` exist?

Comment: What key produces the error? maybe these 2 aren't the same type? ` FOREIGN KEY (privilege_id) REFERENCES privileges_t (privilege_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (created_by) REFERENCES sys_admin_user_t(sys_admin_id),`

Comment: In your example exist table `sys_user_roles_t` from which you try to reference to `sys_admin_user_t` and `privileges_t`, but you don't create `privileges_t`.

Comment: @Harikrishnan Error is: "Cannot add foreign key constraint". Please see above

Comment: thank you all .instead of sys_privileges_t  i refer privileges_t that is the mistake later i find it.

Answer (score 1):

This can occur in the following cases:

- You do not create the table privileges_t
- In your table privileges_t does not exists primary key by field `privilege_id`
- The field `privilege_id` from table sys_user_roles_t are not exactly the same data type as in table privileges_t
- You are not using InnoDB as the engine on all tables

And to find the specific error run this:

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G
```